# What would you call Apollonian circles that are located within polygon

Tags: geometry, algorithms, packing-problem

Sorry, if this question is dumb, but:

When you try to fill the circle with other circles - its called Apollonian circles, and there are resources about it, and some example algorithms. 
But i want to know the name of the generic algorithm of placing circles within the polygon, in same fashion as apollonian ones are placed in the circle.

Comment: thanx for a downvote, my anonymous friend ! _though, hopefully, there are some less hostile math geeks here, who can answer my question_

Comment: I think I would call it an Apollonian packing of the polygon. I don't know if there's a standard name for it.

Comment: Ha! **[Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing)** - its indeed called like that. Thanx, and if you can put your comment as answer, i will accept it (as now i can google my way through it).

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that it is called an Apollonian packing of the polygon.